# IBAction Crashing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, crash, sigabrt

Keep getting an SIGABRT error in my code and I don't know why.
I feel that I am over looking a very simple error and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Every time when I click the UIButton my app crash problem seems to be within IBOutlet.

The SIGABRT error starts at the beginning of the AppDelagate

SignInViewController:

```
import UIKit

import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@objc(SignInViewController)
class SignInViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    //@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

   // @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    var handle: FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
        handle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
            if user != nil {
                MeasurementHelper.sendLoginEvent()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.SignInToFp, sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let handle = handle {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
}
```

Applegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
// UserNotifications are only required for the optional FCM step
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return self.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: "")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error \(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                          accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error)")
                return
            }
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        FIRApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more useful information , from this we can hard to find the source.

Comment: Which UIButton and on which View Controller that button is placed?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to an unused `IBOutlet`.  Right click on each of your outlets in `storyboard` and remove (click the x) any of the outlets that are not being used/not referenced in your `viewcontroller`.